# How to dispose from UIView subviews on one ViewController when navigating away from it

Tags: swift, uikit, viewcontroller, strong-references

I'm starting to learn Swift and decided to build an app but without storyboard.

My SceneDelegate `scene` function instantiates a TabBarController

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let tb = TabBarController()

window?.rootViewController = tb
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.windowScene = windowSceme
```

I have a TabBarController that extends from UITabBarController which pretty much styles the tab bar and sets it all up

For each item of the Tabbar I have a ViewController. For the purpose of this question I'm going to specify the first "Home".

In Home, which extends ViewController, I have the following

```
let homePageView = HomePageView()
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
   navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(true)
   homePageView.setupHomePage()
   view.addSubview(homePageView)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   homePageView.dispose()
}
```

The Controller is pretty much only in charge of calling whatever is going to be displayed on the screen within `HomePageView()`, the main component. This last, holds two more views. One carrousel `HomePageCarrousel()` and one header `HomePageSocialUp()`. This view instantiates the two latter referred to and sets the layout programmatically and adds them as subviews. It also includes a dispose function that sets the instantiated classes to nil such as --> Instantiate - `homePageCarrousel = HomePageCarrousel()` and the dispose function has `homePageCarrousel = nil`

That works perfectly fine but when I navigate away from the current view controller via the tab bar and navigate back to it, now I have two instances of `HomePageCarrousel()` and `HomePageSocialUp()` within `HomeView`

[image: Hierarchy]

I'm probably holding a strong reference somewhere but I can't figure out when. Could someone point me to where should I look to debug it or what might be that is creating the issue.

I'm also providing the code for the two views duplicated in case the issue is there

**HomePageSocialUp**

```
class HomePageSocialUp: UIView {
   
   let logo = UIImage(named: "LogoSmiles")
   let socialImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "tripadvisor")!, UIImage(named: "instagram")!, UIImage(named: "facebook")!, UIImage(named: "linkedin")!]
   
   func setupHeaderCircle() {
      guard let insetTop = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top else {return}
      let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: insetTop + 60), radius: CGFloat(90), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
      
      let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
      shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
      
      shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
      
      layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
   }
   
   func setupSocialHeader() {
      setupHeaderCircle()
      layer.masksToBounds = true;
      
      backgroundColor = UIColor.TintColor
      layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
      layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
      layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
      layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
      layer.masksToBounds = false
      frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 280)
      
      let imageView = UIImageView()
      guard let logo = logo else {return}
      guard let insetTop = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top else {return}
      imageView.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(Int((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - (logo.size.width)))) / 2, y: 120 - (logo.size.width / 2), width: logo.size.width, height: logo.size.height)
      imageView.image = logo
      addSubview(imageView)
      
   }
}
```

**HomePageCarrousel**

```
class HomePageCarrousel: UIScrollView {
   
   
   var images: [UIImage]?
   
   var originX = 0
   var numberOfIterations = 0
   var timer: Timer?
   
   func setupCarrousel() {
      
      let x = (Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) - (Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) - 60)) / 2
      frame = CGRect(x: x, y: (Int(frame.origin.y) - 350) / 2, width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) - 60, height: 350)
      
      let newImage = textToImage(drawText: "Creating Smiles in unique places.", frame: frame, inImage: UIImage(named: "smiles1")!, atPoint: CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x + 20, y: frame.height - 20))
      
      images = [newImage, UIImage(named: "smiles2")!]
      
      guard timer == nil else { return }
      timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(startScrolling), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
      
      guard let imageCount = images?.count, let images = images else { return }
      contentSize = CGSize(width: frame.width * CGFloat(images.count), height: frame.height)
      for image in 0..<imageCount {
         let imageView = UIImageView()
         imageView.image = images[image]
         imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
         imageView.clipsToBounds = true
         
         let xPosition = frame.width * CGFloat(image)
         imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
         addSubview(imageView)
      }
      
      timer?.fire()
   }
   
   func textToImage(drawText text: String, frame: CGRect, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
      let textColor = UIColor.white
      let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold" , size: 12)!
      
      let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)
      
      let textFontAttributes = [
      NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
      NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
      ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
      image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))
      
      text.draw(in: frame, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
      
      let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      
      return newImage!
   }
   @objc func startScrolling() {
      print(originX)
      guard let images = images else { return }
      if originX == images.count {
         originX = 0
         numberOfIterations += 1
      }
      
      if numberOfIterations > 2 {
         timer?.invalidate()
         timer = nil
         numberOfIterations = 0
      }
      
      let x = CGFloat(originX) * frame.size.width
      setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), animated: true)
      originX += 1
   }
}
```

Thanks upfront

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to remove the subviews, something like

```
    homePageView.subviews.forEach { (view) in
    //taking appropriate action to whichever view you want
        view.removeFromSuperview()//for removing views
    }
```

Comment: that is absolutely correct but to get the code in a more swifty way I used subviews.forEach{$0.removeFromSuperview()}